# Multi-parameter context constraints in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm currently reading the paper *Monad Transformers Step by Step*
by Martin Grabmüller.

Theres a part in the paper where he lists off the following instance declaration:

`instance (MonadError e m) => MonadError e (ReaderT r m) where...`

I've looked all over but I can't really find any info on what exactly a multi-parameter constraint like `(Foo a b)` means. I don't totally understand how `e` and `m` work together within the instance head `=> MonadError e (ReaderT r m)`.

How do these multi-parameter constraints work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, a constraint like `Show a` constrains the type variable `a` to represent a showable type. You seem to understand this.

A constraint of the form `C a b` constrains the pair of type variables `a` and `b`. Intuitively, this constrains means that there is a relation between such types.

Consider this fictional class

```
class C a b where
   sum :: a -> b -> (Int, b)
```

Intuitively, the constraint `C a b` means that `a` and `b` can be `sum`med together (in that order!), and the result of that sum will be a pair `(Int, b)`.

In your case you are dealing with

```
class Monad m => MonadError e m | m -> e where
   throwError :: e -> m a
```

Here, `MonadError e m` expresses the following relation between `e` and `m`.

1. `m` is a monad
2. `e` is a type for which we can convert any value `x :: e` into `throwError x :: m a`, for any `a`. Intuitively, this is an "error" type, representing the nature of some error, and `throwError` simply includes such value inside the monad
3. given `m`, there is only one error type `e`. In other words, the relation is actually a function. This is expressed through a functional dependency `... | m -> e` in the class above.

The simple version is: `MonadError m a` means that `m` is a monad which can express some "error values", of type `e`.

For example, if we have `MonadError M String` available, we can write

```
foo :: Int -> M Int
foo n | n == 0    = throwError "can't handle zero!"
      | otherwise = return (100 `div` n)
```